# arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory in cyanogenmod source

Tags: android, linux, gcc, cyanogenmod

I have downloaded a highly compressed version of cyanogenmod 7 source code from xda. I have unzipped the file under /home. However on running `make -j4 otatools` I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

However on opening the location, I can see that the file is present. How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Following files had to be downloaded and installed.

libc66-i386:
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb

lib32ncurses5:
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ncurses/lib32ncurses5_5.7+20100313-5_amd64.deb